В цикле создать новые ссылки. Не могу понят в чем ошибка
есть код
with open('list.txt', 'r') as file:
    ids = file.read().split(',')

for id in ids:
    url = f"https://www.{id}.com"    
    print(url)

В ids - список id. Ожидаю что код будет выводить строки https://www.401.com,
https://www.402.com и т.д.
Результат:
https://www.401
405
406
403
404
2
13
14
24
.com

Как исправить?

Заменить строку
ids = file.read().split(',')

на строку
ids = file.read().split()

если там все-таки есть запятые, убрать
ids = file.read()
ids=ids.replace(',','')
ids=ids.split()


Понял, задав разделитель, которого в файле не было (там в столбик id без разделителей), я тем самым все значения id записал в 1 подстроку. Спасибо, только начинаю изучать python.
